# Position and ID are always returning same value in ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a little problem with my ListView, which does not give me neither the correct position nor id, when being in OnItemLongClickListener.

The ListView displays all entries properly, but on long item click it returns me the sum of entries as the position (doesn't matter on what item I click) and the highest id of all entries. 
As this is the matter, I cannot get the correct id of the entry (which I do have in my custom adapter). What am I doing wrong?

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Here I want to delete the selected entry..
            //both position and id are returning the same value:
            // when there are three items in the list, the position would be three for all entries, 
            // while the id would be the value of the latest entry.
            showDeleteSingleEntryDialog(id);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I populate the list view with using a AsyncTask as follows (by calling the AsyncTask in my OnCreateView inside the fragment)

```
private class DisplayEntriesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    Cursor data;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        data = mDatabaseHelper.getDiaryEntriesCurrentUser(userID);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        if (data == null || data.getCount() < 1) {
            mTextView.setText("Keine Einträge vorhanden!");
        } else {
            try {
                while (data.moveToNext()){
                    listData.add(data.getString(1));
                }
            } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                //...
            }
        }
        adapter = new DiaryCursorAdapter(getContext(), data);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my custom adapter

```
public class DiaryCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

Context context;
private long ident;

public DiaryCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ident = cursor.getLong(0);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_title);
    title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_location);
    location.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_date);
    date.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_content);
    content.setText(cursor.getString(2));
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_diary_entries, parent, false);
    //return view;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return ident;
}}
```

I tried to populate the list view without the AsyncTask. 
By the way, the ListView's parent in the corresponding layout file is a LinearLayout (not a scrollview, as I discovered was a possible issue).

Comment: run [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/SkAPUhuk), what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink Where do I get method `getContentResolver`?

Comment: place that code into `Activity#onCreate`

Comment: Actually the app crashed, but that's the output:

`09-16 22:44:12.002 2491-2491/? D/TelephonyCallback: SignalStrength: 4
09-16 22:44:12.052 2491-2491/? D/TelephonyCallback: DataActivity: 0`

Comment: what crashed? no permission? so add it to the manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Comment: @pskink Yes, it says no permission, although this was already added to the manifest before..

Comment: this is how it should be done: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#Permissions

Comment: Seems that I have another issue here. Permission is defined right after Manifest tag and I also implemented runtime permission  (which is however not called at all).

Comment: @pskink Alright, got that to work. Your provided code seems to work as expected.. 
`09-16 23:20:30.882 6239-6239/de.ur.mi.travelnote D/Test..: onItemLongClick position: 3, id: 4
09-16 23:20:37.782 6239-6239/de.ur.mi.travelnote D/Test..: onItemLongClick position: 5, id: 6
09-16 23:20:39.282 6239-6239/de.ur.mi.travelnote D/Test..: onItemLongClick position: 7, id: 8
09-16 23:20:40.412 6239-6239/de.ur.mi.travelnote D/Test..: onItemLongClick position: 9, id: 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make @pskink and @karora comments an answer:

I've falsely overwritten `getItemID`, which caused the behaviour I described above.

So, removing of the override method did fix my problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The item ID will be being returned ultimately by a call to getItemId(), so you override this to return "ident" which is private to your CursorAdaptor class and will be changed for each row.

You need to change your ident into an ArrayList of ident (or something like that) which you can access by the value of 'position' which is passed into the getItemId() call.

Comment: no, he just needs to delete `getItemId` method - it is already implemented by `CursorAdapter`

Comment: But that would not affect that "position" is always the same when clicking long on an item, would it?

Comment: Regardless of whether deletion, or fixing is the correct answer (and perhaps some of that decision must be informed by the intended functionality), the bug is in the way getItemId currently returns a value which is not related to the position of the item in the list.